# Probability model for repeated survey data

Tags: bayesian, modeling, survey

I'd like to find a suitable probability model but I'm not sure if the one I've thought of makes sense.  The intention is to apply a Bayesian analysis to survey data which has been sampled twice. The setting:

- Individuals are asked a series of nine questions (out of many others)
- These nine questions are yes/no
- The same individuals are asked the same nine questions one year later
- I'd like to know if there has been a change in response over time

Modeling the number of yes's as $X \sim$ Binomial(9, $\theta$) seems obvious, but how should I incorporate the two sampling times? It makes sense to take the number of responses from the second sampling and subtract them from the first sampling and do inference on $\theta_{diff} = \theta_{after} - \theta_{before}$.  However, the difference of Binomial r.v.s is ugly and it would be nice to have conjugacy.

I could just do $X \sim$ Binomial(9, $\theta_{before}$) and $Y \sim$ Binomial(9, $\theta_{after}$) but the questions were answered by the same people.  In other words, why would one perform a two-sample t-test when the information necessary for a paired t-test is available?

Since $X + Y \sim$ Binomial($n_1 + n_2, \theta$) if $X \sim$ Binomial($n_1, \theta$) and $Y \sim$ Binomial($n_2, \theta$), does it make sense to model the the first batch of questions as $X \sim$ Binomial(9, $\theta_{first}$) then add the second batch to the first and model $X + Y \sim$ Binomial(18, $\theta_{both}$) and look at the difference, overlap, etc. of the posteriors of $\theta_{first}$ and $\theta_{both}$?

Am I being too picky about the difference of Binomials?  Am I missing something obvious?  If anyone has suggestions or useful references they would be much appreciated.